# To write 100 from a bunch of threes

Tags: arithmetic, puzzle

My 6th grader got an exercise to write an expression that equals 100 using

- only the digit 3
- no parentheses
- all four operations

We have worked on this for over 30 minutes. How should he even tackle this? We have tried many ways that come close but I may be overthinking. We have tried exponents as well.

Comment: Are there restrictions on the number of times you can use the $3$ or the $+-\times/$ operations?

Comment: Well $3\div 3=1$ so you can do $3\times 3 -3 =6$ to use up the multiples and the minus and then do $3\div 3 + 3\div 3$ 94 times.

Comment: @fleablood: great minds think alike

Comment: Yeah... if you can concatenate numbers just muck about with 33 or 333 to get close.  Use plus or minus 3 to get closer and use 3/3 = 1 to bring it home.  Inelegant and there may (or may not) be a slick direct way with each operation exactly once.  But knowing 3/3=1 means .... it's reasonable to expect it to be doable.

Comment: Just to answer the `How should he even tackle this?` part: trial and error. There is no systematic way to tackle it. Think of it more as of a recreational puzzle than real arithmetic.

Comment: $3\times3\times3\times3+3\times3+3\times3+3\div3+3\div3-3\div3$

Comment: $3\div 3=1$, so $3\div 3+3\div 3+\cdots$ a hundred times gives $100$. You can express all numbers in a similar way so I think there are additional restrictions.

Answer (score 3):

$$ 3 3 \cdot 3 + 3 - 3 + 3 / 3 = 100. $$

$$3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3 + 3\cdot3\cdot3 - 3\cdot3 + 3/3 = 100.$$

Answer (score 1):

Well, clearly $(333-33)\div 3 = 100$.

Now, you just have to write something *equivalent* that does not use parenthesis. Then figure a way to use addition.

Answer (score 1):

You can note that $\frac 33=1$, so you can add or subtract any number you want by adding or subtracting $\frac 33$. We probably want to make things bigger, so choose addition.  Now we just need to use up multiplication and subtraction.  So $3 \times 3 -3=6$ and add $94$ terms of $\frac 33$ to be done.

Answer (score 1):

For another variation not using "adjoined" 3s:

$$3 \times 3 \times 3 \times 3 + 3 \times 3 + 3 \times 3 + 3 - 3 \div 3 - 3 \div 3 = 81 + 9 + 9 + 3 - 1 - 1 = 100$$

Answer (score 0):

Is there a limit on the number of times you can use the operation?

Otherwise it seems you could do

$$3\times 33 + 3\div 3 +3\div 3 - 3\div 3$$

Comment: This is the same as $(3\times 33) + (3\div 3) + (3\div 3) - (3\div 3) = 99+1+1-1=100$

Answer (score 0):

If we can use addition and division more than one times then it can be solved easily.

By using division three times and addition two times we can write expression,

$$3÷3+3÷3+33×3-3÷3$$
Now using order of operation(PEMDAS) solve expression.

$$1+1+99-1$$
$$=100$$
It can also solved by various types, like

$$33×3+\dfrac{3+3}{3}-3÷3$$
$$99+\dfrac{3+3}{3}-1$$
$$99+2-1$$
$$=100$$
I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

$$3333/33-33/3+3\cdot 3+3/3=\\101-11+9+1=100$$

If one is allowed to skip any of the 4 operations we can do

$$33\cdot 3 + 3/3=99+1=100$$